# Как получить контекст в BroadcastReceiver при закрытом приложении?

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, context

Есть `BroadcastReceiver` , в который передаются данные для активации будильника по расписанию. Я знаю, что `BroadcastReceiver` работает в фоне даже после закрытия приложения, проверено. Но есть проблема - я не могу получить `Context`, если приложение закрыто.

**Манифест:**

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context mContext;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

...

    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

    toast();
}

private void toast() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Уведомление не показывается. Любой другой код, который не использует `Context`, работает отлично при закрытом приложении. При открытом приложении никаких проблем нет.

Как получить `Context` и показать уведомление при закрытом приложении?

Comment: Ресивер тоже часть вашего приложения - поэтому на момент его работы приложение в статусе не "закрыто", а "запущено". Проблема в другом - вы не можете выводить что либо поверх других приложений (из фона, то есть) без специальных привелегий (насколько помню `SYSTEM_ALERT`, но в последних версиях Андроида он вроде запрещён, *но это не точно*))). Уведомление в статус бар (`Notification`) вы можете вывести беспрепятственно (хотя тоже есть нюансы с разрешениями от юзера).

Comment: передайте контекст который приходит как параметр